C# Windows Form Add Button Not Adding Data and Closing Form
I have a KhachHang.cs file with code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QuanLyKhachHangWinApp.Class
{
    class KhachHang //Customer
    {
        private int _MaKH; //ID
        private string _TenKH; //Name
        private string _GioiTinh; //Sex
        private string _SDT; //Phone
        private DateTime _NgaySinh; //DOB
        private string _LoaiKH; //Type of Customer

        public KhachHang()
        {
        }

        public KhachHang(int maKH, string tenKH, string gioiTinh, string sDT, DateTime ngaySinh, string loaiKH)
        {
            _MaKH = maKH;
            _TenKH = tenKH;
            _GioiTinh = gioiTinh;
            _SDT = sDT;
            _NgaySinh = ngaySinh;
            _LoaiKH = loaiKH;
        }

        public int MaKH { get => _MaKH; set => _MaKH = value; }
        public string TenKH { get => _TenKH; set => _TenKH = value; }
        public string GioiTinh { get => _GioiTinh; set => _GioiTinh = value; }
        public string SDT { get => _SDT; set => _SDT = value; }
        public DateTime NgaySinh { get => _NgaySinh; set => _NgaySinh = value; }
        public string LoaiKH { get => _LoaiKH; set => _LoaiKH = value; }

        public void ThemKhachHang(KhachHang khachHang) 
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = Connection.GetSqlConnection();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ThemKhachHang", sqlConnection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MaKH", khachHang.MaKH));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TenKH", khachHang.TenKH));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GioiTinh", khachHang.GioiTinh));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SDT", khachHang.SDT));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NgaySinh", khachHang.NgaySinh));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LoaiKH", khachHang.LoaiKH));

            sqlConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}

And type of these properties of Customer in SQL server have data type, I make sure the SQL server was connected with C# (because of the default data from SQL was update to my Main Form)
CREATE TABLE KHACHHANG
(
MaKH int primary key,
TenKH nvarchar(50),
GioiTinh char(3) check (GioiTinh in ('Nam','Nu')),
SDT char(20),
NgaySinh DATE,
LoaiKH char(10) check (LoaiKH in ('VIP','Thuong'))
)
GO*/

and then I have a frmAdd.cs file
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using QuanLyKhachHangWinApp.Class;

namespace QuanLyKhachHangWinApp
{
    public partial class frmAdd : Form
    {
        public frmAdd()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

      
        
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void frmAdd_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bntAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThemKhachHang();
            this.Close();
        }

        void ThemKhachHang()
        {

            KhachHang khachHang = new KhachHang();
            // Điền thông tin cho khachHang từ các trường nhập liệu trên form
            khachHang.MaKH = int.Parse(txtIDNew.Text);
            khachHang.TenKH = txtNameNew.Text;
            khachHang.GioiTinh = cboSexNew.SelectedItem.ToString();
            khachHang.SDT = txtPhoneNew.Text;
            khachHang.NgaySinh = DateTime.Parse(dtmDateAdd.Text);
            khachHang.LoaiKH = cboTypeCustomerNew.SelectedItem.ToString();
            khachHang.ThemKhachHang(khachHang);
        }

    }
}

My code did not throw any error, but it did not work like I want
I run code, it will appear frmAdd.cs (it did appear) but when I enter data from the keyboard into the field in form and press Add button, the Add button did not work(it did not add my data and close the form). I expect the data will be Add in SQL server and close the form.
because My code did not throw any error, I don't know how to fix it (is there an inadequacy in the data type I have set or passed in?)

Try calling the same stored procedure in SQL Management Studio and check if it is working or not

I checked and my procedure works normally

Can u share the procedure?

CREATE PROCEDURE ThemKhachHang @MaKH int, @TenKH nvarchar(50), @GioiTinh char(3), @SDT char(20), @NgaySinh DATE, @LoaiKH char(10) AS BEGIN IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM KHACHHANG WHERE MaKH = @MaKH)     IF @GioiTinh IN ('Nam', 'Nu')     BEGIN     IF @LoaiKH IN ('VIP', 'Thuong')     BEGIN     INSERT INTO KHACHHANG (MaKH, TenKH, GioiTinh, SDT, NgaySinh, LoaiKH)     VALUES (@MaKH, @TenKH, @GioiTinh, @SDT, @NgaySinh, @LoaiKH)  END  END END

I checked it and it's working properly, maybe the values you are entering is not correct and not meeting your conditions which are:

"@GioiTinh" values outside the range of (Nam, Nu)
"@LoaiKH" values outside the range of (VIP, Thuong)

And last thing that @MaKH value is not already added to the table

However I recommend to use "using" for SqlConnection and SqlCommand to dispose the objects automatically after finish in order to avoid memory leaks

I'm sorry but what does it mean when you said '@MaKH value is not already add to table while 'CREATE PROCEDURE Teaching @MaKH int'

gioiTinh va loaiKH in my form are combobox, ngaySinh in my form is datetime but in SQL sever I set it as DATE type so I wonder 'khachHang.MaKH = int.Parse(txtIDNew.Text);
khachHang.TenKH = txtNameNew.Text;
khachHang.GioiTinh = cboSexNew.SelectedItem.ToString();
khachHang.SDT = txtPhoneNew.Text;
khachHang.NgaySinh = DateTime.Parse(dtmDateAdd.Text);
khachHang.LoaiKH = cboTypeCustomerNew.SelectedItem.ToString();
khachHang.ThemKhachHang(khachHang);'    the way I input data is true

Make sure then the id you are passing is not exists in the database, database collation is not case sensitive

Ok, I've been able to fix my code and it worked normally
